# How to call a class from another drive

Tags: c#, class

I have created a formula for my application. I know that there are many decompilers to break my application, I want to call a class file from my server and save it in my destination path like C:\test\Formula.cs and call it from my exe file where it is located from

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication8\WindowsFormsApplication8\bin\Debug\myApp.exe
```

Similarly, since you can read a text file like this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\test.txt");
```

I want to read my class like this:

```
Class readerclass = new Class("C:\\test\\Formula.cs");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to distribute .cs files with your application and compile and load them at runtime? why?

Comment: there is a formula i dont want anyone to know it because there are many decompilers which can decompile my app i want to call the class and delete it after work is finished

Comment: But if you distribute the .cs file it makes it even easier to view the code, no decompilation is necessary!!

Comment: LOL so you want to download the PLAIN TEXT instead?!

Comment: If you don't want to distribute the code because you fear people reverse-engineering it, then just host it behind a web-service and have your client app call the webservice.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Remember, consider accepting an answer if it helped solve your problem. People will be more likely to answer your questions in the future if you keep a high accept-rate.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. C# is a compiled language! You can't just pull the source down and try to run it.  To do this you would have to compile it on-the-fly and read in the resulting assembly, etc. It would be a disaster.

Now if you had compiled assemblies hosted on the server, you could **theoretically** download them, load them with `Assembly.LoadFrom()` and then instantiate classes from that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either create a `library` project that contains the formula.cs (dll) or `include/add` this formula.cs file into your current project.